# Selichoth with Tallith and Tefillin

Tags: tefilin, zemanim, tallit-gadol, selichot, yuhara

Assuming one is saying *selichoth* during the time of *tallith* and *tefillin* (e.g. ~6AM in the greater New York metropolitan area), should one put them on first or wait till after *selichoth*? Does it make a difference if the congregation one is praying with waits till after *selichoth*, assuming they are *not* necessarily doing so based on an actual halachic ruling, but rather due to having changed from an earlier time of recital (prior to zman tefillin) to the later one, without adjusting their tefillin-wearing practice?  Would it be considered *michzi keyuhara* (pretentious)?

Comment: Note that in all circumstances, the chazzan should certainly be wearing a tallit.

Comment: http://www.eretzhemdah.org/qna.asp?pageid=3&lang=en&cat=&str=tallit+and+tefillin+during+selichot

Comment: @rosends - he writes what I am tempted to, i.e. that the Poskim don't discuss issues that shouldn't happen. :-)